# Flutter CircleAvatar with a radius above 27 in a ListTile becomes an ellipse

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having an issue with this, I need a CircleAvatar with a Radius of 35, but anything above 27, placed in a ListTile makes it an ellipse, constraining the height. In the container above it is displayed properly with Radius 40. Any ideas?

```
           Card(
              elevation: 0,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 27,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/sophia_hs.jpg'),
                ),
                title:
                Text("Sophia Daniels",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle:
                Text("Casting Director",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 120,
              color: Color(0xffffd504),
              child: Center(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/sophia_hs.jpg'),
                  ),
                  dense: false,
                  title: Text("Sophia Daniels",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text("Casting Director",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihtsy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the height of the container and make it bigger than 120.
You could also try Image.Asset() to load images from assets. They have more ability to fit the image according to it's size.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting squares with 27 pixels size. http://prntscr.com/scm36q . 

leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 80,
                        child: Image.asset('images/sophia_hs.jpg'),
                      ),

Comment: Looks like the height of the leading widget of ListTile cannot be increased as per this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/29771. We need to create a custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, wrap the "CircleAvatar" with radius greater than 27 and "ListTile" in a row as shown below:

```
Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 32,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/sophia_hs.jpg'),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Sophia Daniels",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Casting Director",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

ListTile should be enclosed in a Flexible to avoid "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width" error.